# Discrepancy in introducing Schottky barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, electronics

I have a problem regarding introduction of [Schottky barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schottky_barrier) in metal-semiconductor junction. Because of this barrier the energies of conduction band vary discontinuously and hence the potential is discontinuous. So, the electric field which is derivative of potential will be infinite near the junction. So, how to resolve this apparent contradiction?

Comment: The bands aren't discontinuous because the junction isn't infinitely thin. The energy level varies continuously (but steeply) across the junction. The force on carriers is indeed very high, but it acts only over a very short distance. The force times distance is of course equal to the difference in the energy levels.

Comment: Agreeing with John, but trying to clarify.  The thought experiment of Schottky was what would happen if he brought two materials together where there was an offset in the Fermi energies, and just "pinned" them at that offset.  Then he calculated how the carriers redistribute themselves in response to this thought-experiment discontinuity, resulting in the formation of the junction, which then removes the discontinuity introduced by the thought-experiment.

Comment: Thanx guys! I got it.